# Unable to print iframe pdf content in IE 11.contentWindow.document.execCommand trigger print dialog box but it return empty page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

var target = document.getElementById('printPDF');
target.contentWindow.document.execCommand('print', false, null);

Comment: Is the target inside the iframe by any chance? An iframe has it's own document, so you need to select from a reference to the frame, something like `var target = document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow.document.getElementById('printPDF');` So basically the reverse of what you're trying. Get the iframe and select everything from that root, not the other way around.

Comment: It is not working.. IE11  contentWindow is not working. contentWindow.document.execCommand print the empty page..

Comment: This is causing alot of issues in IE11. Might be easier to just insert the pdf into the main window and print that, or window.open() another tab and paste the pdf there.

Comment: function myFunction() {                                                                     var 
        x.focus();
        x.contentWindow.print();} IE 11  it's not working so I am using    var printdoc = document.getElementById('printPDF'); 
    printdoc.contentWindow.document.execCommand('print', false, null); print dialog box is open but it print empty page. If the source is image its working fine.

Comment: @Shilly They need the requirement like that.. Is there is any other way to do?